# Why any class with EdmEntityTypeAttribute causes runtime error even if it's not used?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net, entity, entity-relationship

I created ADO.NET Entity Data Model. Let's say that it generated the code below:

```
namespace MyEntities
{
       //Contexts
       ...
       [EdmEntityTypeAttribute(NamespaceName="Entities", Name="table1")]
       [Serializable()]
       [DataContractAttribute(IsReference=true)]
       public partial class table1 : EntityObject{...}
}
```

Any manipulation on it works fine. For example

```
var cxt = new SPEntities();
var res = (from t in cxt.table1
           select t).ToList();
```

But if I add **ANY** class with attribute `[EdmEntityTypeAttribute]` within **DIFFERENT** namespace from table1 class, but in the **SAME** assembly that table1 class is located, so I get runtime errors like: `The type doesn't have any key members.`, `"Schema specified is not valid.` Let's say I add this class:

```
 namespace ANY_NAMESPACE
    {
        [EdmEntityTypeAttribute]
        public class ANY_CLASS
        {
        }
    }
```

Why I get those kind errors if I even don't use ANY_CLASS class?

It looks like ADO.NET Entity engine passes through all classes with `[EdmEntityTypeAttribute]` attribute in the **ASSEMBLY** before it execute the code and checks those classes for correct construction even if they aren't used. Am I right? If I do, why it does it?

Thank you